# Possible to write an Ecto query that unions multiple tables without writing raw SQL?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Background:

I am writing a simple Q/A website. Very much like Stackoverflow, in this site, a user can like/upvote a question, an answer, or a comment.

Question:

I am struggling to write an Ecto query that can return all of the questions, answers, or comments that a user has liked/upvoted.

Specifically, I would like to write a query that:

1. Returns all questions, comments, and answer upvoted by a specific user as a single list
2. And have the list of questions, answers, and comments sorted by when they were upvoted

This query seems like it may require UNION, which is [not yet supported by ecto 2.0](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/issues/1549) from my understanding.

Therefore, I am wondering if someone can show me or point me to the right direction on tackling such a query in Ecto. Thank you for any help.

Here are the schemas for the relevant models.

...

```
schema "users" do
  ...

  has_many :answer_upvotes, AnswerUpvote
  has_many :comment_upvotes, CommentUpvote
  has_many :question_upvotes, QuestionUpvote

  many_to_many :upvoted_answers, Answer, join_through: AnswerUpvote
  many_to_many :upvoted_comments, Comment, join_through: CommentUpvote
  many_to_many :upvoted_questions, Question, join_through: QuestionUpvote

  timestamps
end
```

...

```
schema "answer_upvotes" do
  belongs_to :answer, Answer
  belongs_to :user, User

  timestamps
end
```

...

```
schema "comment_upvotes" do
  belongs_to :comment, Comment
  belongs_to :user, User

  timestamps
end
```

...

```
schema "question_upvotes" do
  belongs_to :question, Question
  belongs_to :user, User

  timestamps
end
```

...

```
schema "questions" do
  ...   

  belongs_to :user, User

  has_many :answers, Answer
  has_many :upvotes, QuestionUpvote

  many_to_many :upvoting_users, User, join_through: QuestionUpvote

  timestamps
end
```

...

```
schema "answers" do
  ...

  belongs_to :question, Question
  belongs_to :user, User

  has_many :comments, Comment
  has_many :upvotes, AnswerUpvote

  many_to_many :upvoting_users, User, join_through: AnswerUpvote

  timestamps
end
```

...

```
schema "comments" do
  ...

  belongs_to :answer, Answer
  belongs_to :user, User

  has_many :upvotes, CommentUpvote

  many_to_many :upvoting_users, User, join_through: CommentUpvote

  timestamps
end
```

**Edit**

I can write a query to order questions, answers, or items by their upvoted date individually.

For example:

```
upvoted_answers_query =
  from answer in Answer,
    join: upvote in assoc(answer, :upvotes), where: upvote.user_id == ^user.id,
    order_by: upvote.inserted_at
    select: answer
```

But I am not sure how to write one, single Ecto query that can retrieve of all upvoted questions, answers, and comments by a user without using unions or writing raw SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not currently supported but there is an open ticket: https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/issues/1549

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the open ticket. I guess there is not yet a workaround to union other than writing raw SQL query and execute it ecto?

Comment: Yup - although if you do so benchmark it - in a lot of cases it is faster to just run separate queries and ++ them together

    thing =
      blah_blah
      |> Repo.all
      |> Kernel.++(
           blah_blah_blah
           |> Repo.all
         )

Answer (score 5):

Ecto v3.0.0 (2018-10-29) added support for `union` and `union_all`.

Example from docs:

```
supplier_query = from s in Supplier, select: s.city
from c in Customer, select: c.city, union: ^supplier_query
```

https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#union/2